# Asp.Net chunking cookie issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Identity. The login app is .NET6, the apps themselves are .NET 4.8 I followed this article to set this up and it works fine... just about https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/21987

In the .NET 6 Startup.cs:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => 
    ...
    options.CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager()
    ...
```

In the Startup.Auth.cs in the .NET 4.8 Apps:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions 
{
    ...
    CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager()
    ...
```

The .4.8 CookieManager comes from Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure
The .NET 6 CookieManager comes from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies

Everything works perfectly... apart from, if I have enough claims in the cookie for it to be larger than 4096 .. hence splitting into two cookies. At that point the .NET 6 app is fine, but the .Net 4.8 doesn't recognize that it is logged on, and redirects back to the login page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this.

The issue is the Asp.NET `ChunkedCookieManager` reads/writes the original cookie as `chunks:X` while the ASP.NET Core `ChunkedCookieManager` reads/writes it as `chunks-X`  Note the dash vs colon.

My fix was to write a `AspNetCompatChunkedCookieManager` for .NET Core that was just a copy/paste of `ChunkedCookieManager` with a different value for the prefix const.